# Korean language not rendering on PDF while using JSPDF

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf, jspdf

I am using JSPDF library to generate pdf while working on korean language the letters are getting change in symbols and sometime empty. Could anyone please help me?

```
const doc = new jsPDF();

const myFont = ... // overhere i am inserting a string which is being generated using following link https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html(it's too long)
```

// add the font to jsPDF

```
doc.addFileToVFS("MyFont.ttf", myFont);
doc.addFont("MyFont.ttf", "MyFont", "normal");
doc.setFont("MyFont");
```

Comment: Does your font contains glyphs for Korean language? What encoding you set for your PDF?

Comment: https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+KR?subset=korean  I am using the following font.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jsPDF - fromHTML and custom fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279675/jspdf-fromhtml-and-custom-fonts)

Comment: No i have tried it but no luck.

Comment: `const myFont = "APT/+AD0AAQACQAJAAQABADzAPMA9ADzAPMA9AD0AGcA/wD/AP8A/wD/AQAAAA==";

     // add the font to jsPDF
     doc.addFileToVFS("NotoSansKR-Regular.ttf", myFont);
     doc.addFont("NotoSansKR-Regular.ttf", "NotoSansKR-Regular", "normal");
     doc.setFont('NotoSansKR-Regular','normal');`

Answer (score 0):

You can try directly print the HTML text element.

Shameless plug :
[generate-pdf-from-react-html](https://github.com/Milen-Minchev/generate-pdf-from-react-html)